# Create an array of classes in Java (not objects)?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I want to create an array of classes, not objects. I want to be able to access static functions of each class that have the same name, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    array[i].staticMethod();
}
```

Where array[i] would be syntactically interchangable with the name of a class, like `Integer`.

Comment: I also must add a base function to the type of the array, like so: class `SuperClass { public static void staticMethod() {} }`, but I tried to do so with the `Class` class and it failed due to `Class` being declared `final`.

Comment: I have to wonder if this might be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What's the overall problem that you're trying to solve with this construct?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot polymorphically access a method of a class without the method being declared within the base class. I cannot do so within `Class`.

Comment: I want to compare the efficiency of sorting algorithms, where each sorting class has a static method `sort()` and I put each class within an array.

Comment: And this method needs to be static, because ...?

Comment: "If this path down you go, only pain will you find." --Yoda.

Comment: Okay, I got this to work by defining a parent class named `Sorter` and having each sorter class extend it, then declaring an array of `Sorter` objects. But I also had to instantiate each sorter class despite each class exclusively consisting of static methods. Will this cause any run-time overhead compared to instead using an array of non-instantiated classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really have any choice but to use `Class` *objects* in an array, `Class<?>[] array = new Class<?>[10]`, and then invoke the static method reflectively, e.g.

```
array[i].getMethod("staticMethod", ArgType1.class, ArgType2.class)
    .invoke(null, arg1, arg2);
```

Given your stated goal, that is the very closest approximation available in Java.  You cannot have lowercase-c `class`es stored as variables or as data in arrays.

EDIT: Given your stated goal of benchmarking the efficiency of sorting algorithms, then reflection overhead would skew those results unpleasantly.  You're better off finding another way to write it, rather than what you're trying to do with an array of classes, which won't really work.

if you're in Java 8, then I'd probably write something like

```
List<Consumer<int[]>> sorters = Arrays.asList(
    Sort1::sort, Sort2::sort, Sort3::sort);
for (Consumer<int[]> sorter : sort) {
  int[] array = createNewRandomArray();
  sorter.accept(array);
}
```

If you're not, then I'd write something like

```
   enum SortingVariant {
     SORT1 {
       @Override void sort(int[] array) { Sort1.sort(array); }
     },
     SORT2 {
       @Override void sort(int[] array) { Sort2.sort(array); }
     };
     abstract void sort(int[] array);
   }

   for (SortingVariant sorter : SortingVariant.values()) {
     sorter.sort(getNewRandomArray());
   }
```

In both these cases, the key goal is to create a list of objects which implement a known method that can be used to sort, rather than trying to magically create a list of classes and invoke a method that happens to have the same name in each of them.

Answer (score 2):

You define an array of classes like this:

```
Class<?>[] classArray = new Class<?>[10];
```

Comment: but you can't call staticMethod

Comment: You'd have to use reflection